# Mapping OPTION + MINUS key in skhd

Tags: keybindings

I would like to map out the key combination <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to shift focus to another monitor using yabai using skhd. Something like this:

```
alt - MINUS : yabai -m display --focus recent
```

However, I have not been able to figure out what to put in for "MINUS". I know that skhd can take keycodes as arguments. However, I'm not sure how to get the keycode for <kbd>-</kbd>. I used the [Key Codes](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) application and put in the values I got there but none seem to work.

```
Key Down
    Characters: -
    Unicode:        45 / 0x2d
    Keys:       -
    Key Code:   27 / 0x1b
    Modifiers:  256 / 0x100
```

Comment: I use AZERTY (French) keyboard the minus key outputs 0x18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `skhd --observe` command to find the keycode to use.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the `skhd --observe` command.

P.S. If the keycode has letters, please use capital letters.